# WebCam Image Capture and face Detection with angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with angular 9, to open a webcam and capture an image I used a webcam component (ngx-webcam).
Then, I want to add face detection to my code and when I click on the button "snapshot" I want to get the last frame once the face is detected.

This is my code below:

.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div>
      <webcam class="webcam" [width]="500" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)" *ngIf="showWebcam"
              [allowCameraSwitch]="allowCameraSwitch" [switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable"
              [videoOptions]="videoOptions"
              [imageQuality]="1"
              (cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)"
              (initError)="handleInitError($event)"
      ></webcam>
      <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="triggerSnapshot();">Take A Snapshot</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggleWebcam();">Toggle Webcam</button>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showNextWebcam(true);" [disabled]="!multipleWebcamsAvailable">Next Webcam</button>
      <input id="cameraSwitchCheckbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="allowCameraSwitch"><label for="cameraSwitchCheckbox">Allow Camera Switch</label>
      <br/>
     <!-- DeviceId: <input id="deviceId" type="text" [(ngModel)]="deviceId" style="width: 500px">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showNextWebcam(deviceId);">Activate</button>-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="snapshot" *ngIf="webcamImage">
    <h2>Nice one!</h2>
    <img [src]="webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl"/>
  </div>



  <h4 *ngIf="errors.length > 0">Messages:</h4>
  <ul *ngFor="let error of errors">
    <li>{{error | json}}</li>
  </ul>
```

.ts

```
 public triggerSnapshot(): void {
   this.trigger.next();
  this.imageservice.imageid= this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl;
 }

 public toggleWebcam(): void {
   this.showWebcam = !this.showWebcam;
 }

 public handleInitError(error: WebcamInitError): void {
   this.errors.push(error);
 }

 public showNextWebcam(directionOrDeviceId: boolean|string): void {
   this.nextWebcam.next(directionOrDeviceId);
 }

 public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
   console.info('received webcam image', webcamImage);
   this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
 }

 public cameraWasSwitched(deviceId: string): void {
   this.deviceId = deviceId;
 }
```

Comment: minor text adjustments

Comment: @omarabdelkefi have you found solution for this? I am having a similar kind of requirement.